# Round Robin for gRPC (nodejs) on kubernetes with headless service

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, grpc

I have a a 3 nodejs grpc server pods and a headless kubernetes service for the grpc service (returns all 3 pod ips with dns tested with getent hosts from within the pod). However all grpc client request always end up at a single server.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39756233/2952128 (last paragraph) round robin per call should be possible Q1 2017. I am using grpc 1.1.2

I tried to give `{"loadBalancingPolicy": "round-robin"}` as options for `new Client(address, credentials, options)` and use `dns:///service:port` as address. If I understand documentation/code correctly this should be handed down to the c-core and use the newly implemented round robin channel creation. (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/service_config.md)

Is this how round-robin load balancer is supposed to work now? Is it already released with grpc 1.1.2?

Comment: Have you tried service type:ClusterIP? It should work fine with round-robin. Keep in mind that a gRPC client might be caching the connection, so if you are testing with only one client, then it might be because of gRPC.

Comment: Yes I tried that too. It behaves the same. Also not sure if that would be correct as I am expecting Client Side Round Robin of gRPC. [link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md). Because as I understand it thats exactly the Idea to have many cached open connections and change on a per call basis. So all the Clients need all the IPs thats why i tried Headless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After diving deep into Grpc-c core code and the nodejs adapter I found that it works by using the option key `"grpc.lb_policy_name"`. Therefore, constructing the gRPC client with

```
new Client(address, credentials, {"grpc.lb_policy_name": "round_robin"})
```

works.
Note that in my original question I also used `round-robin` instead of the correct `round_robin`

I am still not completely sure how to set the `serviceConfig` from the service side with nodejs instead of using client (channel) option override.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps, but [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1982) discussion shows how to implement load balancing strategies via `grpc.service_config`.

```js
const options = {
    'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': ...,
    'grpc.lb_policy_name': 'round_robin', // <--- has no effect in grpc-js
    'grpc.service_config': JSON.stringify({ loadBalancingConfig: [{ round_robin: {} }] }),  // <--- but this still works
};
```

Comment: This is a correct answer if you using npm package @grpc/grpc-js